# Does (spontaneous) symmetry breaking imply long-range order and vice-versa?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, correlation-functions

Crystalline solids have a long-range order (where symmetry is broken) but liquids have only a short-range order (where no symmetry is broken). Ferromagnets have a long-range magnetic order while a paramagnet lacks it. The converse also seems to be true, for example, in the Kosterlitz-Thouless transition there is no symmetry breaking and there is no long-range order (but quasi long-range). By long-range order, I understand that below some critical temperature $T_c$ the two-point correlation function of the order parameter (density) becomes a constant (independent of position).

*Is this a generic feature? In other words, does long-range order necessarily imply the symmetry-breaking? And does the symmetry-breaking necessarily imply the long-range order?*

Comment: Symmetry breaking implies long-range order (of a suitable kind). But there can be long-range order without any symmetry breaking.

Comment: "_there can be long-range order without symmetry breaking_" Can you give an example what you have in mind?

Comment: Ok, as a trivial example, consider the following variant of the Ising model with an additional 3-body term: $H=-\sum_{i\sim j}\sigma_i\sigma_j - h\sum_i \sigma_i - \epsilon\sum_{i\sim j\sim k}\sigma_i\sigma_j\sigma_k$, where $\sim$ means "nearest neighbors". This Hamiltonian has no internal symmetry when $\epsilon$ is non zero. But one can prove that, for any small $\epsilon>0$ and any temperature large enough, one can find a value of $h$ such that there is long-range order (existence of two Gibbs states with positive, resp. negative, magnetization).

Comment: If you want to know how to analyze this kind of systems, there is a whole mathematical theory devoted to it: the Pirogov-Sinai theory. See, for example, chapter 7 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Since I'm a physics student the link of your book is too technical for me.

Comment: Not necessarily (I was a physics student too). We wrote the book with advanced undergraduates physics students in mind too, not only mathematicians...

Comment: @YvanVelenik Okay. Still it's too involved and I need some time to go through it. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Great, I hope you'll like it, once you see that it is actually not so involved. Of course, I wouldn't advise to start with Chapter 7.

Comment: Are you looking for a rigorous answer - i.e. which aspects of this can be proven? Or are you looking for the "typical" intuition behind this?  Also, you do you *define* SSB and LRO in the first place?  (I mean, there are clear definitions, but many physicists even use them synonymously -- I once got asked "what do you even mean" by a colleague when I pointed out they were a priori different concepts.)

Comment: I second @NorbertSchuch : there are different answers possible depending on one's definition of SSB and LRO. The OP should add their desired definition (or explicitly state that (s)he would be happy with whatever definition an answerer might prefer). Relatedly, if one counts LRO of 'string orders', then there are clear counter-examples to the supposed equivalence.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Well, if I were to choose whatever definition I want, I would just choose the same for both.  It would tremendously simplify the proof.  (There are clear concepts anyways; even more clear for Gibbs states rather than ground states.)  --- I'm not sure it's entirely fair to count string orders; the problem is even without that incredible tricky.

Comment: The variant  Ising model (7.1.1  in  Yvan's book) is addressed as an example..  Yvan said that  this Hamiltonian has no internal symmetry when ϵ is non zero.   I see that this  modified model  loses the global spin flipping symmetry,  an obvious symmetry when $\epsilon=0$. Nevertheless,  can one guarantee non-existence of `any internal symmetry'? One can naturally identify  any classical spin model  with  a special quantum model by introducing all Pauli matrices, $x,y,z$. Then any $A=A^\ast$ such that $[H, A]=0$  generates a symmetry for $H$. There are many such symmetries.

Comment: In 7.1.1 Yvan mentioned  the only possible ground states $\eta^{+}$, $\eta^{-}$ that are mapped to each other by the global flipping symmetry. But the ground state case is known to be exceptional.  I conjecture that for thermal equilibrium states (defined by the DLR condition)  such situation hardly happen. Could  you provide your answer on the relationship between LRO vs SSB  for the thermal equilibrium case at positive temperature?

Answer (score 2):

There are some subtleties, but the answer is basically "yes" in local, translationally invariant systems, because of the [cluster decomposition property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decomposition_theorem). Empirically, virtually any "realistic" physical system satisfies the property that
$$\lim_{|x - y| \to \infty} \left[ \langle A(x)\, B(y) \rangle - \langle A(x) \rangle \langle B(y) \rangle \right] = 0$$
for any local operators $A(x)$ and $B(y)$. In other words, correlations decay with distance, so expectation values of faraway observables are uncorrelated. (One can derive this result from various technical locality assumptions.) If $m(x)$ is a local symmetry-breaking order parameter, then $\langle m(x) \rangle \equiv \bar{m}$ is constant by translational invariance, so if we let $A(x) = B(x) = m(x)$ in the identity above then we have
$$\lim_{|x - y| \to \infty} \langle m(x)\, m(y) \rangle = \bar{m}^2.$$
The left-hand side being nonzero defines long-range order, and the right-hand side being nonzero defines spontaneous symmetry breaking, so we see that either implies the other.

Comment: The clustering property is NOT true in this form for degenerate ground states, which is exactly what is needed in the case of SSB!  Also, how do you define SSB - your argument seems rather circular!  Wouldn't you define SSB as "if I put a small perturbation, I get a spontaneous magnetization", and LRO as "there are long-range correlations"? --- I mean, where does the claim of equality in the second equation even come from?!  ---  To me, your answer sounds  a bit like "it's true because we know it's true".

Comment: @NorbertSchuch (a) The cluster property certainly holds for the non-cat degenerate ground states, which are the ones that are physically observed. (b) I'm defining SSB as "when experimentalists measure the symmetry-breaking order parameter $m(x)$, they find a nonzero value." (c) The second equality follows from the first.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call this a "definition", since it very much depends on the experimental setup, but so it be -- and I think this can indeed be closely related to the formal definition of SSB.  Ok, then: How do you define LRO?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The existence of a symmetry-breaking local order parameter $m(x)$ such that $$\lim_{|x-y| \to \infty} \langle m(x)\ m(y) \rangle = C \neq 0.$$ Unlike SSB, this can't be determined via local measurements.

Comment: But if you only look at states with the clustering property, this is trivially the same. And can thus be determined by local measurements.

Comment: @tparker Thanks for the answer. Is there a general formula when $|x-y|$ is finite (whose limit $|x-y|\to \infty$ gives your first equation)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The nontrivial fact, which requires nonlocal measurements to verify, is that physical states are always experimentally observed to respect cluster decomposition. There is still some theoretical disagreement as to why. Once you accept this, then the equivalence between SSB and LRO becomes trivial (at least in translationally invariant systems).

Comment: @SRS Not an exact one that holds in general. The correlation function's behavior is very system-dependent at distances less than or comparable to the correlation length $\xi$. But the asymptotic form of the correlation function for distances much longer than the correlation length is typically an exponential decay $\sim \exp(-|x-y|/\xi)$ above the critical temperature, a power-law decay $\sim 1/|x-y|^p$ at the critical temperature, and of the form $\sim C + \exp(-|x-y|/\xi)$ below the critical temperature.

Comment: @tparker Then you should just say it's trivial and that's it.  The next step would be to explain the heuristic connection between the two concepts given some mean field (=clustering) ansatz.  But the point is the concepts are different: E.g. -- if you forget the quantum matter and look at Gibbs states -- LRO is also observed in Gibbs states, which DO NOT break symmetry.  The mystery is: Whenever there is a symmetry and the Gibbs state has LRO, then the Gibbs state w/ a small perturbation is symmetry breaking.  (Similarly for finite volume ground states.)  This is a pretty non-trivial ...

Comment: ... connection, which can be explained heuristically with some mean field type arguments, yet (AFAIK) has resisted rigorous assesments.  (Not to mention the quantitative relation between the LRO value and the magnetization.)  Note that this is not purely mathematical -- e.g., in QMC it is exxactly the LRO which is measured to compute the (alledged) spontaneous magnetization.